# Django. How to display list of objects in one line using for loop in templates?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I want to display list of objects in one line using django template tags,
That piece of code:

`{%  for object in my_objects  %}
    <p>  {{  object  }}  </p>
{%  endfor  %}`

gives me that kind of result:

```
obj1 
obj2
obj3
.
.
.
etc.
```

Is there any way, to get that kind of result(with comas):

```
obj1, obj2, obj3,  ... etc.
```

Thank You for anwsers.

Comment: Two good answers below.  This question is really an html question, not django

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you try ?

```
<p>
{% for object in my_objects %} 
    {{ object }}{% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %} 
{% endfor %}
</p>
```

Comment: You're right I forgot it, my post is now edited. Thanks rnevius.

Comment: You might also want to remove the space between `{{ object }}` and `{% if` ... `:)`

Comment: What if each object was a clickable link? How can we do it?

Answer (score 6):

Simpler solution than the one given by Totem:

```
{{ my_objects|join:', ' }}
```

Comment: This is the most elegant and not-so-obvious solution.

Comment: very elegant! best companion of `{{ objects | unordered_list}}` !

Comment: Nice solution. I wonder how it's going to work if each object has "a href"?