# Print for loop output in one line django templates

Tags: python, html, django

I've this piece of code:

```
{% for a in doctor.treatment.all %}
  <p>  {{a}}  </p>
{% endfor %}
```

It gives me the output like this:

```
Teeth Whitening
Braces
Veneers
```

Is there anyway I can get it like this in the templates in one line with commas?

```
Teeth Whitening, Braces, Veneers.
```

Comment: in html i have not any idea .... but in python you can put every **doctor.treatment** in a string with a ', ' character end of each ... using **Join**. then send that string to request page

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27356191/django-how-to-display-list-of-objects-in-one-line-using-for-loop-in-templates/27356260

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See `join` - 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#join

This should work

```
<p>
{{ doctor.treatment.all|join:", "  }}.
</p>
```

Comment: What if each doctor's treatment was a clickable link?

Answer (score 0):

`<p></p>` is a paragraph, it will cause a line break.

I think the following code will work for you:

```
<p>
    {% for a in doctor.treatment.all %}
        {{a}}{% if a == doctor.treatment.all[-1] %},&ensp;{% else %}.{% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</p>
```

`join` is better.

Comment: have you checked your solution? It does not match the desired output

Comment: you mean the white space(`&ensp;`)?

Comment: I mean the trailing comma.