# How to get rid of dict_keys() in my django template?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-templates

I am trying to print comma separated key values after drilling into a dictionary. But I am unable to get rid of `dict_keys()` that shows in my output.

Here is my template:

*metrics.html*

```
<h1>Accessing values</h1>
<p>{{ final_metrics.values }} </p>
<p>{{final_metrics.data.0.13.browser.Chrome}}</p>

<h1>{{ final_metrics.month }} Clicks Statistics</h1>
<p>Short Url: {{final_metrics.short_url }}</p>
<p>Date Accessed: {{ final_metrics.data.0.keys }}</p>  
<p>Browser: {{final_metrics.data.0.13.browser.keys}}</p>
<p>Platform: {{final_metrics.data.0.13.platform.keys}}</p>
```

and on the output screen it shows as follows

[image: output]

Is there a way to get rid of the `dict_keys()` and have those values in a comma separated format?

I have tried the solutions from https://stackoverflow.com/a/8000091 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/34542858 but does not seem to work for me.

Comment: It's gross, but this will always work: `{% for i in final_metrics.data.0.keys %}{{i}}{% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}{% endfor %}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll throw it in as an answer, but there might be a prettier way of doing it

#### base

```html
{% for i in dictionary.keys %}{{i}}{% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}{% endfor %}
```

#### full

```html
<h1>Accessing values</h1>
<p>{{ final_metrics.values }} </p>
<p>{{final_metrics.data.0.13.browser.Chrome}}</p>

<h1>{{ final_metrics.month }} Clicks Statistics</h1>
<p>Short Url: {{final_metrics.short_url }}</p>
<p>Date Accessed: {% for i in final_metrics.data.0.keys %}{{i}}{% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}{% endfor %}</p>  
<p>Browser: {% for i in final_metrics.data.0.13.browser.keys %}{{i}}{% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}{% endfor %}</p>
<p>Platform: {% for i in final_metrics.data.0.13.platform.keys %}{{i}}{% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}{% endfor %}</p>
```